# Can't login to MySQL Root user

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to set up a connection in MySQL workbench but my login is always denied. I tried the default of 'root' and any other password I may have accidentally changed it to but none of them work. I have tried following some forum posts on how to reset a root password but regardless of what commands I put in to the terminal, I get errors left, right, and centre. I get errors such as files missing, syntax error, and unrecognised command.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwXYK.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ef1Ow.png)

Comment: It will be better if you put 2 - 4 different outputs of the commands you are running and its errors and also the output of the error you get in MySQL workbench.

Comment: If you are having an authentication problem with a just-installed server, reinstall it.

Comment: tried a reinstall... no change

Comment: What do you mean no change. You reinstall the server and you receive a new password